# how to look for alias name in Cisco MDS switch

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, switch

I 've cisco MDS switch(9506). I have created aliases ,now i want to check for the alias name like  "CLAR4682_spa2" .
*I 've the wwn info. with me and i want to make use of it to find the alias name 
 Please help me find the right command to use in CLI.

In brocade nodefind "wwn" gives that information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh hello again wildchild - if you let me know what version of SAN-OS or NX-OS you're using I'll happily send you a copy of Cisco's excellent command reference.

Comment: thanks chopper: here's the info Hardware cisco MDS 9509 ("Supervisor/Fabric-1") Intel(R) Pentium(R) III CPU with 1028596 kB of memory. Processor Board ID JAB0933014R bootflash: 250368 kB slot0: 0 kB swemc001 kernel uptime is 331 days 15 hours 20 minute(s) 3 second(s) Last reset Reason: Unknown System version: 3.2(3a) Service: ==============================================      Software BIOS: version 1.1.0 loader: version 1.2(2) kickstart: version 3.2(3a) system: version 3.2(3a)

Comment: Ok, here's the link - it's a really great reference - http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/storage/san_switches/mds9000/sw/rel_3_x/command/reference/CR03.pdf

By the way you're REALLY behind on your code, I've got lots of 9509's and haven't seen a v3 box for...literally years now - you should consider upgrading.

Comment: yes i know, but it's up to the management to decide based on the budget and stuff :)..however, i will put this point forward in discussion. Thanks you again for the response.

Comment: I'm no expert on licence terms but you might want to call Cisco to ask if you can get a free update.